# Can we change the name of rpool?

Tags: zfs, solaris-10, zpool

Can we change the name of rpool? Do we have to create a new BE(Boot Environment)? Can anyone tell me the complete process?

```
# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
 scrub: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
          c1t3d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

# zfs list
# zfs list
NAME                      USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                    6.49G  60.4G    40K  /rpool
rpool/ROOT               3.46G  60.4G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/solaris       3.46G  60.4G  3.16G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var    303M  60.4G   216M  /var
rpool/dump               2.00G  60.5G  1.94G  -
rpool/export             96.5K  60.4G    32K  /rpool/export
rpool/export/home        64.5K  60.4G    32K  /rpool/export/home
rpool/export/home/admin  32.5K  60.4G  32.5K  /rpool/export/home/admin
rpool/swap               1.03G  60.5G  1.00G  -
```

Comment: What you research so far?

Comment: And give me serious reason to rename root pool.

Comment: Here we have many machines with multiple replicas and backups and it helps to be able to see the machine name in the filesystem paths, so we name our root pools.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of the pool, you should merely import it (which implies of course previous export) with the new name; however for root pool this requires the single mode and/or booting up from the alternate zfs-capable source.

It's also worth mentioning that, as you were told, there's no obvious reason to rename the root pool: yours is named after the Solaris naming convention, which I personally find fancy and cool.